# Windows refuses to scan SSD disk

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, chkdsk

In the last weeks my Windows 10 pc has been throwing blue screens (Multiple times a day). Viewing the Event Viewer I've found that all crashes are related to this error:

[image]

So I run the chkdsk command as suggested, and given that it's the `C:` drive it must be rebooted. While booting Windows prompts a 10s message saying that if I want to stop the scan I should press a key (No key pressed) and it instantly boots.

Looking at the next entries in the Event Viewer I see that are volumes are marked as healthy, EXCEPT the `C:` drive which has no entry at all (Not faulty or healthy), so I think it has not been scanned or repaired.

All entries after reboot looks like this one, but no one refers to the `\Device\HarddiskVolume5` that is causing the error

[image]

Is there any reason why Windows would refuse to scan an SSD drive? Any ideas how to force the repair?

Comment: I would boot with a W10 repair disk and try chkdsk offline.

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/131907/how-to-create-and-use-a-recovery-drive-or-system-repair-disc-in-windows-8/